# error regarding change in datatype in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains a string instead of nan values and whenever i try to drop rows containing it, it gives an error with the label:

```
KeyError: 'SALE PRICE'
```

where, "SALE PRICE" is the column containing those values, I am trying to create a decision tree for the data please help
The code:

```
y = df["SALE PRICE"]
print(y.dtypes)
y = y[y['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  ']
y[['SALE PRICE']] = y[['SALE PRICE']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
y = y.dropna()
```

error:

```
 <ipython-input-60-433cf81cd3fd> in <module>
      1 y = df["SALE PRICE"]
      2 print(y.dtypes)
----> 3 y = y[y['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  ']
      4 y[['SALE PRICE']] = y[['SALE PRICE']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
      5 y = y.dropna()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1066         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1067         try:
-> 1068             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1069 
   1070             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'SALE PRICE'
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you're trying to use won't work, I'll explain what your code is doing:

```
y = df["SALE PRICE"]
```

This line uses the selects the column `"SALE PRICE"` from your dataframe called `df` and sets it to the variable `y`. Note that the object returned is a `pd.Series` object which doesn't have columns. You can check object types by running `type(df)` and also `type(y)`.

When you run:

```
y = y[y['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  ']
```

Your code is looking in the index of the series stored in the variable `y` (which is probably a range from 0 to the number of rows you have) for the string `"SALE PRICE"` which doesn't exist. You can check the index of y by using `y.index`.

You can either replace your `y`'s with `df` or if you want to store the name of your column for use in other places you'll need to just store the string to the variable, something like:

```
y = "SALE PRICE" #
print(df[y]) # Identical to running df["SALE PRICE"]
```